# How can a worker (thread) reserve disk space and communicate the reservation with other workers

Tags: celery, distributed-computing

I am trying to set up an autoscaling class that will check the disk resource to see if a worker can safely run. The disk usage can be estimated prior to running. What are some option for a worker to share this information with other workers?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best option is to write your own inspect command. See [the documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#writing-your-own-remote-control-commands) on how to do that, there's an example at the end of the section.

Comment: I guess I could make it work, although it seems like inspect is more geared towards inter-worker communication than concurrent process communcation. I am resorting to using [Reject](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#reject) and using autoscaler to adjust available workers. Thanks for the suggestion despite my limited description.